# Is there any attribute of <li> tags that I could use for storing server-side Id(s) of items(s)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to store server-side Id(s) of items within an attribute defined on `<li>` tags, such that I could retrieve them within JS methods when there is a click event on them.

Is there any attribute that I could use to store this kind of data?

I tried putting server side ids of items into `id` attribute of `<li>` tags but it doesnt allow ids starting with digits 
 !

Comment: What server side technology are you using? What "doesn't work there" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 introduces `data-` attributes which can be very useful in cases such as this one.

```
<li data-something="test">...</li>
```

Then, in JavaScript, you can fetch using:

```
elem.getAttribute('data-something');
```

or (not IE supported):

```
elem.dataset.something;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9g33e/

Comment: And "HTML5 introduced" pretty much means "HTML5 standardized a mechanism that already works with plenty of browsers that pre-date HTML5, but which was never standardized or documented before".

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: It would indeed work, but I don't think a webpage passes the W3C validation with self-made attributes in HTML4.

Comment: That's right, of course. I was just trying to tell people not to be discouraged by the name HTML5, which (unfortunately) often is understood as "will work in *some future browser*, eventually". This is **not** the case here.

Answer (score 3):

generally, you should use `data-*` attributes..

```
<li data-myInformation="123">This is item 123</li>
```

These can be retrieved easily, and popular frameworks such as jQuery support easy access to these attributes with a `element.data("myInformation")` method.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your problem correctly, then there shouldn't be a problem using the `id` attribute, unless of course you are already using that for another purpose.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) shows the valid attributes for `li` elements:

`id`, `class`, `lang`, `dir`, `title`, `style`, and a bunch of event handler attributes (`onclick` and the like).

In theory you could use pretty much any of those to store your data, but `id` would be my preferred choice. However, it's important to remember that `id` attribute values have to start with a letter (unless you're using the doctype mentioned below, but in that case it would be better to use the below method anyway).

As others have mentioned, if you are using a `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype, then you can use the new [`data-*` attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) which are intended for this exact use.

Comment: Be careful with using the `id` attribute if the server-side id is numeric as that attribute "Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z" - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

Comment: Good point, but also remember that when using the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype, in which case they can begin with pretty much anything: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class